# Hyundai tester software

Tags: hyundai, testing, software

Is there any PC software to see the sensors value and change there parameters, or how I can do that for my Hyundai.

Comment: year and model of car might be relevant.

Comment: You can see what the sensors are reading using a OBD-II scanner. I would not attempt to change any values unless you have a ton of experience, or if you are willing to ruin the engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any PC software, but the Torque android app has the Advanced Hyundai LT plugin available (both cost a little money). Get a bluetooth ELM328 OBDII sender, and you should be able to see everything you need. I'm not sure about changing the parameters, though - you should read up on the Hyundai LT plugin to see if it can do that.